# How to add new columns according to other columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I looked over other questions but couldn't find what I wanted.
Here is my short dataset

```
    Year    Region      value
0   2016    London      31720.0
1   2016    Beijing     502631.0
2   2016    Tokyo       817262.0
3   2016    Bangkok     1021768.0
4   2016    Akihabara   894094.0
5   2017    London      515113.0
6   2017    Beijing     78737.0
```

Now, I wanted to another two new columns according to the "Region" Column.
Here are two columns

```
lat = ["14.6937 ","14.64792 ","14.35806 ","14.10594","14.1825"]
long = ["-17.44406","-16.24363","-16.58583"," -15.5508","-16.25333"]
```

I wanted to add the lat and long in the place given by their Region. Also the regions are coming many time, If anyone can help me, It would be great.

Comment: how do you identify which latitude position is for which region?

Comment: Hey @RajatMishra, the first 5 latitudes,longitude are serialized !

Comment: what i meant was how to identifiy if "14.6937" is related to London or Beijing ?

Comment: That's the question I have in mind @RajatMishra... For ex3-the first five cities are London, beijing, tokyo, bangkok and similarly their respective latitides and long are in the order as given. I am also not understanding how to add two columns lat and long when Region is Tokyo, choose this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I have assumed that `lat` and `long` are mapping to the city in the same order as they occur in the main dataframe i.e. London maps to 14.6937 and -17.44406.

I can extract the cities for a given year and create a new dataframe having city, long and lat details.

```
In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017], 
    ...: 'city':['London','Beijing','Tokyo','Bangkok','Akihabara','London','Beijing'], 
    ...: 'value':[560234,557335,6938935,503804,4224,5632,34424]})                                                                                                                                         

In [45]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[45]: 
   year       city    value
0  2016     London   560234
1  2016    Beijing   557335
2  2016      Tokyo  6938935
3  2016    Bangkok   503804
4  2016  Akihabara     4224
5  2017     London     5632
6  2017    Beijing    34424

In [46]: lat = ["14.6937 ","14.64792 ","14.35806 ","14.10594","14.1825"] 
    ...: long = ["-17.44406","-16.24363","-16.58583"," -15.5508","-16.25333"]                                                                                                                             

In [54]: cities = df['city'].unique().tolist()                                                                                                                                                            
In [56]: cities                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[56]: ['London', 'Beijing', 'Tokyo', 'Bangkok', 'Akihabara']

In [49]: city_details = pd.DataFrame({'city':cities, 'lat':lat, 'long':long})                                                                                                                               

In [50]: city_details                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[50]: 
        city        lat       long
0     London   14.6937   -17.44406
1    Beijing  14.64792   -16.24363
2      Tokyo  14.35806   -16.58583
3    Bangkok   14.10594   -15.5508
4  Akihabara    14.1825  -16.25333
```

There are two data frames with a common key 'city', Using `pd.merge()`, one can join the two data frames to get the details.

```
In [51]: df.merge(city_details,how='inner',on='city')                                                                                                                                                     
Out[51]: 
   year       city    value        lat       long
0  2016     London   560234   14.6937   -17.44406
1  2017     London     5632   14.6937   -17.44406
2  2016    Beijing   557335  14.64792   -16.24363
3  2017    Beijing    34424  14.64792   -16.24363
4  2016      Tokyo  6938935  14.35806   -16.58583
5  2016    Bangkok   503804   14.10594   -15.5508
6  2016  Akihabara     4224    14.1825  -16.25333
```